# inserting values in postgresql database from textfields in python

Tags: wxpython, postgresql-9.1

I am trying inserting values from a textfield in wxpyhton GUI. When I tried inserting value through a Textctrl, its giving me an error as "can't adapt type 'TextCtrl'"

This is my TextCtrl:

```
user=wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,value="Hello ")
```

And I used insert statement as:

```
cur.execute ('insert into users values(%s)' , (user))
```

Whats the correct method of inserting values from textctrl or other controls like checkboxes,dropdown etc  into postgresql?

Comment: `user` is just the reference to the TextCtrl object, not the value itself. Try using `user.GetValue()` instead of `user` in the execute line. Also I'm not sure but I think `?` might be the place holder for the text rather than `%s`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually grab the data from the text control, not pass the text control object itself. The usual method is: user.GetValue().

I have written a couple articles on wxPython and databases using SQLAlchemy. They might help you figure this stuff out too:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/11/10/wxpython-and-sqlalchemy-an-intro-to-mvc-and-crud/
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/06/04/wxpython-and-sqlalchemy-loading-random-sqlite-databases-for-viewing/